# shift register confusion

Tags: shift-register

[image]

It is a typical picture of a shift register. Assuming initially the clock is off, and serial input=1. After a while clock turns on, and immediately Q_2 becomes D_2=1, but since the clock is common to all flip flops, Q_2=1 means D_1=1, and Since the clock is still on D_1 SHOULD BE EQUAL TO Q_1, so, D_2=Q_2=D_1=Q_1=1, Similarly in can be shown that just after one clock pulse the serial input=1=serial output, which is not how the shift register should work. What is missing here?

Comment: *What is missing here?* - set up time for data prior to a clock edge and propagation delay. D type flip flops are edge driven and not level driven.

Comment: There is a small but finite delay from the clock edge until the Q output actually changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After a while clock turns on, and **immediately** Q<sub>2</sub> becomes D<sub>2</sub> = 1, but since the clock is common to all flip flops, Q<sub>2</sub> = 1 means D<sub>1</sub> = 1, and since the clock is still on D<sub>1</sub> SHOULD BE EQUAL TO Q<sub>1</sub>, so, D<sub>2</sub> = Q<sub>2</sub> = D<sub>1</sub>=Q<sub>1</sub> = 1.

Flip-flops are edge-triggered.

The outputs do not change immediately. There is a propagation delay.

*Timing diagram.*

```
         ________________________________________________
D2    __|
               _______              ________
Clock ________|       |____________|        |____________
                _________________________________________
Q2    _________|
                                     ____________________
Q1    ______________________________|
```

Note the delay between the clock and the Qs turning on.

Answer (score 1):

Edge triggered latches and flip-flops have *set-up* times. This is the minimum time a value must be present on an input prior to the edge trigger in order for the device to "register" that input. If the clock edges arrive at each flip-flop simultaneously, even if the flip-flop had no propagation delay, a new value appearing at the output of a flip-flop will arrive at the input of the next flip-flop *too late* to meet the minimum set-up time, and so the 2nd flip-flop will not be toggled by that value. The minimum set-up time, and also the propagation delay prevent a change one flip-flop from rippling all the way down a shift register.

[image]

(Image from [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Setup-time-t-su-hold-time-t-h-and-clock-to-q-delay-d-cq-of-a-flipflop_fig2_323349911))

In the image, \$t_{su}\$ is the setup time, and \$d_{cq}\$ is the propagation delay.